# How to make multi select Checkbox or Listview in Jquery Mobile through array of ID and name

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing in Jquery Mobile, and i want to show list of people and out of them i want to select some people and save them to database. How will i show the list with multiple selection ?

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate a bit more, You mean you want to create HTML Checkboxes with a list of people to be selected, and whoever is selected gets stored to the database?

Comment: i am getting list of people through JSON and thats in array. and i want to show that in listview or checkbox so that user can select some people from the list. and while saving it will be saved in database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a small example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var array = [{ name: "John", value: "1"}, { name: "Alex", value: "2"},{ name: "John2", value: "3"}, { name: "Alex2", value: "4"}];

        function createCheckboxes(){
         $("#createBtn").remove();
         $("#content").append('<fieldset id="cbFieldSet" data-role="controlgroup">');
         var length = array.length;
         for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
            $("#cbFieldSet").append('<input type="checkbox" name="cb-'+i+'" id="cb-'+i+'" value="'+array[i].name+'"/><label for="cb-'+i+'">'+array[i].name+'</label>');
         }

         $("#content").trigger("create");
         $("#showBtn").css("visibility","visible");
        }

        function showSelectedNames(){
            var count = $("#cbFieldSet input:checked").length;
            var str = '';
            for(i=0;i<count;i++){
                str += ' '+$("#cbFieldSet input:checked")[i].value;
            }
            alert("You selected----"+str);
        }
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page1</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="content">    
        <a id="createBtn" data-role="button" onclick="createCheckboxes()">Create checkbox list from array</a>
        <a id="showBtn" data-role="button" onclick="showSelectedNames()" style="visibility:hidden">Alert selected names</a>     
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

 </body>
</html>
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/DqqK8/

Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

So you can write a function to parse the list you have and output the html checkboxes, all with one name like:

```
< input type='checkbox' name='persons[]' value='jb' /> John Brown
< input type='checkbox' name='persons[]' value='ts' /> Tim Slim
```

Then in your server side script, say if both checkboxes are checked you will recieve an array like

```
persons("0" => "jb", "1"=>"ts")
```

You can then do validation from there and store into your database.

So if you have var people = [{ name: John, value: 1}, { name: Alex, value: 2}];
go through the array like:

```
for(person in people)
{ 
    output "<input type='checkbox' name='people[]' value='person[value]'>person[name]";
}
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: i have an array like  var array = [{
                            name: John,
                            value: 1},
                        {
                            name: Alex,
                            value: 2}];  and now how can i set this array in checkbox or list view so that can select multiple people ?

Comment: go through the array like: for(){ output "<input type='checkbox' name='people[]' value='value'>name";}

Comment: var array = [{ name: John, value: 1}, { name: Alex, value: 2}];
                    for(people in array)
                        { 
                            
                            //chkDIv is the name of the div 
                        
                           $("#chkDIv").append("<input type='checkbox' name='people[]' value='array[value]'>array[name]");
                        } Do u mean this ? but its not working

Comment: I think you need to do:
$("#chkDIv").append("<input type='checkbox' name='people[]' value='" + array[value] + "'>" + array[name]); and it would a good idea to put it all in a form

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Joshua, Really thankful for your help.. But i tried that also. i tried to just alert(array[name]) but still i am not getting anything in the loop..